# Problems with scheduling tasks from a UI .continuewith task

Tags: c#, task

My application schedules a long running task using the following code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>((a) => WorkTask1(),
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
    .ContinueWith(antecedent => WorkCompletedTask1(antecedent.Result),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

WorkCompletedTask1 is scheduled and displays results on the UI as expected. Depending on results from WorkTask1, WorkCompletedTask1 may schedule additional tasks using the following statement:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>((a) => WorkTask2(),
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
    .ContinueWith(antecedent => WorkCompletedTask2(antecedent.Result),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

WorkTask2 does NOT run on a separate thread as expected; it runs on the UI thread which is blocked until WorkTask2 completes. I thought the TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning would guarantee a separate thread.

Any suggestions on why this does not work? I can schedule addition tasks from UI and non-UI tasks, just not from a .continuewith task in the UI.

**Broken Sample Project Code**

In an empty Windows Forms project with `button1` button on the form, this code does NOT work as expected (Windows 7 VS2010 Express Net 4.0). T2 and T3 run in the UI thread, not a worker thread.
Add a listBox1 to your button1 form and try the following:

```
private delegate void DelegateSendMsg(String msg);
private DelegateSendMsg m_DelegateSendMsg;
private TaskScheduler uiSched;
private Process thisProcess;
private string
    thisProcessName,
    thisProcessId,
    uiThreadName,
    nonuiStatus = "Non-UI",
    uiStatus = "UI";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    thisProcessName = thisProcess.ProcessName;
    thisProcessId = thisProcess.Id.ToString();
    uiThreadName = CurrentThread;
    m_DelegateSendMsg = this.SendMsg;
    uiSched = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    SendMsg("UI thread name is " + CurrentThread);
}

//create the name of the current task
public string CurrentThread
{
    get
    {
        string threadId = null;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Thread.CurrentThread.Name))
            threadId = thisProcess.Id.ToString() + "=" + thisProcessName;
        else
            threadId = thisProcessId
                + "=" + thisProcessName
                + "/" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
        threadId += ":" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " ";
        return threadId;
    }
}

//validate if the function is running in the expected UI state or not
public bool MeetsUIExpectations(string functionName, string expectedStatus)
{
    bool rc = true;
    string currentThreadName = CurrentThread;
    string text = 
        "Function " + functionName + " running in thread " + currentThreadName;
    if ((currentThreadName == uiThreadName) & expectedStatus == uiStatus)
        text += ": UI status as expected";
    else if ((currentThreadName != uiThreadName) & expectedStatus == nonuiStatus)
        text += ": non-UI status as expected";
    else
    {
        text += ": UI status is NOT as expected!"
            + "  Expected: " + expectedStatus
            + "; running in thread" + currentThreadName;
        rc = false;
    }
    SendMsg(text);
    return rc;
}

//display a single text message
private void SendMsg(String msg)
{   
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        try { this.Invoke(m_DelegateSendMsg, "UI context switch: " + msg); }
        catch (Exception) { }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(msg);
        listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>((a) =>
        T1(), TaskScheduler.Default,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
        .ContinueWith(antecedent => T1Completed(antecedent.Result), uiSched);
}

private bool T1()
{
    //get the name of the currently running function and validate UI status
    var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    MeetsUIExpectations(currentMethod.ToString(), nonuiStatus);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < Int32.MaxValue) i++;
    return true;
}

private void T1Completed(bool successful)
{
    var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    MeetsUIExpectations(currentMethod.ToString(), uiStatus);
    if (successful)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>((a) =>
            T2(), TaskScheduler.Default,
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
            .ContinueWith(antecedent => T2Completed(antecedent.Result), uiSched);
    }
}

private bool T2()
{
    var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    MeetsUIExpectations(currentMethod.ToString(), nonuiStatus);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Int32.MaxValue) i++;
    return true;
}

private void T2Completed(bool successful)
{
    var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    MeetsUIExpectations(currentMethod.ToString(), uiStatus);
    Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>((a) =>
        T3(), TaskScheduler.Default,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
        .ContinueWith(antecedent => T3Completed(antecedent.Result), uiSched);
}

private bool T3()
{
    var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    MeetsUIExpectations(currentMethod.ToString(), nonuiStatus);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Int32.MaxValue) i++;
    return true;
}

private void T3Completed(bool successful)
{
    //get the name of the currently running function and validate UI status
    var currentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    MeetsUIExpectations(currentMethod.ToString(), uiStatus);
    SendMsg("All functions completed");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 you have to pass `TaskScheduler.Default` explicitly. You picked the wrong overload to to this (see below).

**Some General Stuff**

In a continuation on the UI thread the `TaskScheduler` is still *UI thread* returned by `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` method. Therefore, all new `Tasks` you start are scheduled on the UI thread too unless you **pass a `TaskScheduler` explicitly**:

Here is a code sample:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(foo => {}, TaskScheduler.Default)
```

Feel free to use whatever `TaskScheduler` you need, but you need to state it explicitly.

**Get the Right Overload**

There are quite a few overloads for `StartNew<T>`. In your code below you pick the wrong one, which causes `TaskScheduler.Default` to act as `state` (a value passed as `a` to `T3`) rather than the *actual scheduler*:

```
var options = TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
    | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent;

// overload with Func<bool>, CancellationToken, options and TaskScheduler
Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => T2(), new CancellationToken(),
    options, TaskScheduler.Default);

// overload with Func<object, bool> with state and options
// scheduler acts as state here instead of actual scheduler, and
// is therefore just passed as (a) to T3 (state is an object, thus
// can also be a TaskScheduler instance)
Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>((a) => T3(),
    TaskScheduler.Default, // state, not scheduler
    options);
```

Obviously this way you won't get the scheduling you want, but the *default behaviour* described above.

**Additional Information for .NET 4.5**

In .NET 4.5, there is [`TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions.aspx) to change this behavior. See [New TaskCreationOptions and TaskContinuationOptions in .NET 4.5 by Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5.aspx) for more details on the new options and let me quote a code sample out of it:

```
// code sample copied from blog post stated above
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{ 
    // #2 long-running work, so offloaded to non-UI thread 
}).ContinueWith(t => 
{ 
    // #3 back on the UI thread 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        // #4 compute-intensive work we want offloaded to non-UI thread (bug!) 
    }); 
}, CancellationToken.None,
TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler, // <-- new option stated in text
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

**Working Sample Project Code**

In an empty Windows Forms project with `button1` button on the form, this code works as expected (Windows 7, .NET 4.0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var uiSched = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    button1.Enabled = false;

    // this HardWork-task is not blocking, as we have
    // TaskScheduler.Default as the default scheduler
    Task.Factory.StartNew(HardWork)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;

            // this HardWork-task will block, as we are on the
            // UI thread scheduler
            Task.Factory.StartNew(HardWork)
                .ContinueWith(t2 =>
                {
                    button1.Enabled = false;

                    // this one will not, as we pass TaskScheduler.Default
                    // explicitly
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(HardWork,
                        new CancellationToken(),
                        TaskCreationOptions.None,
                        TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(t3 =>
                        {
                            button1.Enabled = true;
                        }, uiSched);  // come back to UI thread to alter button1
                }, uiSched); // come back to UI thread to alter button1
        }, uiSched); // come back on UI thread to alter button1
}

public void HardWork()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < Int32.MaxValue) i++;
}
```

Comment: I have been burned by this before. Tasks inherit TaskScheduler.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I understand the reasoning behind propagating the initial TaskScheduler. I still have the same problem even after adding the TaskScheduler.Default parameter. Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>((a) => WorkTask2(), TaskScheduler.Default,
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
    .ContinueWith(antecedent => WorkCompletedTask2(antecedent.Result),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Comment: That's strange. I added some sample code I tried out (and it worked) in an empty project. Do you see differences or could you post some more details of your code?

Comment: @user1912926 Quite a tricky one. You picked the wrong overload and treated your `TaskScheduler` as state. See *Get the Right Overload* edit I made to my post. Ctrl+Shift+Space in Visual Studio opens a tooltip with the method parameters - might help you if you ever stumble across such a problem again.

Comment: @user1912926 Glad to have helped you. Could you accept the answer if it solved your problem? :)

Comment: I had to google how to accept the answer. Thanks again for your patience and your help.