# Task.Factory.StartNew freezing the UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

In the below code when I am scheduling new Task (Task.Factory.StartNew), it is freezing UI. Can anyone help me to understand what's wrong here.

```
public Task ShowHierarchy(IHierarchyFilterStrategy topHierarchyStrategy, IHierarchyFilterStrategy bottomHierarchyStrategy)
{
      IEnumerable<IHierarchyNodeViewModel> topList = null;
      IEnumerable<IHierarchyNodeViewModel> bottomList = null;
      var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
      var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
          topList = topHierarchyStrategy != null ? topHierarchyStrategy.RetrieveHierarchy().ToList() : null;
          bottomList = bottomHierarchyStrategy != null
               ? bottomHierarchyStrategy.RetrieveHierarchy().ToList()
               : null;
      });

      return task.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
      {
          View.SetAvailableNodes(topList, bottomList);
      }, context);
}
```

EDIT:
to be more specific... my UI is getting block on

```
topList = topHierarchyStrategy != null ? topHierarchyStrategy.RetrieveHierarchy().ToList() : null;
```

RetrieveHierarchy() method is to load some data from cache if not in cache then go to DB to get the data. it has nothing to do with UI.

To summrize, what I am doing here is, I am getting two lists from cache/DB in first task and in second task, using these two values to update the UI (some tree nodes). but UI freeze only when it try to retrive value from RetrieveHierarchy() method in the first line, no where else.

The issue occured only first time when data comes from DB. Once it is loaded in cache, no time taken by this line/no UI frozon.

using below line to call ShowHierarchy() method

ShowHierarchy(topHierarchyStrategy, bottomHierarchyStrategy);

I am not using it's return value anywhere.

Comment: How does `RetrieveHierarchy` method looks like? Does that implementation block the UI thread? or maybe `SetAvailableNodes` is too expensive?

Comment: How would we reproduce this since we don't have the full code?

Comment: Try seeing your answer at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934274/problems-with-scheduling-tasks-from-a-ui-continuewith-task)

Comment: I am not sure. Can you give me some hints that I can check at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I needed to provide task creation option to LongRunning. Here is updated code...

```
public Task ShowHierarchy(IHierarchyFilterStrategy topHierarchyStrategy, IHierarchyFilterStrategy bottomHierarchyStrategy)
        {
            IEnumerable<IHierarchyNodeViewModel> topList = null;
            IEnumerable<IHierarchyNodeViewModel> bottomList = null;
            var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            var options = TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
    | TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent;
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                topList = topHierarchyStrategy != null ? topHierarchyStrategy.RetrieveHierarchy().ToList() : null;
                bottomList = bottomHierarchyStrategy != null
                    ? bottomHierarchyStrategy.RetrieveHierarchy().ToList()
                    : null;
            },CancellationToken.None,options, TaskScheduler.Default);

            return task.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
            {
                View.SetAvailableNodes(topList, bottomList);
            }, context);
        }
```

This code is working as expected and not blocking the UI. Please let me know if anyone notice anything un-usual/unexpected with this code.

Comment: `LongRunning` should not affect this. What happens when you use `TaskScheduler.Default` without `LongRunning`?

Answer (score 2):

Given the code you've posted I'm not 100% sure why your UI would lock up. Here are a few suggestions / hints to try and fix the issue.

a) Since you're using the `Task` class, you should also have access to the `async / await` keywords. Mark your method with `async` and then inside you can safely wait for the tasks to complete.

Something like:

```
public async Task ShowHierarchy(IHierarchyFilterStrategy topHierarchyStrategy, IHierarchyFilterStrategy bottomHierarchyStrategy)
{
  ...
  var topListTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    topHierarchyStrategy != null ? topHierarchyStrategy.RetrieveHierarchy().ToList() : null;
  });
   var bottomListTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    bottomList = bottomHierarchyStrategy != null
               ? bottomHierarchyStrategy.RetrieveHierarchy().ToList()
               : null;
  });
  await Task.WhenAll(topListTask, bottomListTask);
  //do things with topList, bottomList - they'll be ready at this point
}
```

b) In most cases you can make do without using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, when using the `async / await` pattern.

c) You can get results from tasks when working with the `await` keyword. You could rework the code to await two different tasks for each of the lists (top and bottom). The good thing about it is that the code is simpler and easier to debug. The downside is that you're not performing the tasks in parallel, so it could take longer. It's worth a try - simpler code is easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks shaamaan... but I cannot use async/await as I am using .NET4.0

however, I found the solution and adding to this thread for everyone else use.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution @Abhash786. Since `async/await` is quite crucial nowadays when working with `Task` I suggest that in any future questions you note that `asyn/await` is unavailable right from the start. ;)

Comment: Sure... I will mentioned this from next time. That would be great if you can review my solution and tell me if it looks oK to you.

Comment: @Abhash786 Quite frankly I'm having a hard time telling if it's OK or not. Sounds like it's working fine, so there's that. ;) Personally I feel like it's more complicated than it ought to be, but it's just a gut feeling and without seeing the whole code I can't really tell if I'm right or wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs